# Web3js - Internal Transaction Data (Event Logs): Token Transfers, Contract Creations, & Internal ETH Transfers

Tags: web3js, erc-20, events, etherscan, internal-transactions

I'm currently recording transaction data via Web3js, while directly connected to a local Geth full archive node via IPC, and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to record internal transaction data (aka 'Event Logs' according to Etherscan.io).

More specifically I'm looking to record ALL ERC-20 token transfers, internal contract creations, and internal transactions (for ex: ETH returned to addresses from Smart Contracts such as CEX / DEX wallets, Primablock, etc).

As of now I'm able to retrieve both ERC-20 token transfers & some internally created contracts using the code snippet posted towards the bottom of this post.

---

I wasn't entirely sure of three things:

1. Are all ERC-20 token transfers are listed with the "0xddf252..."
   sha3 hash, and would the below code suffice for accurately capturing those transfers? Is there a separate function for new tokens minted, or is it safe to assume all newly minted tokens come from the '0x000000...' address?
2. Is there a specific sha3 hash associated with contract created internally?
       The 'contractInternalHash = 0xef4c86' value below is associated with
       new smart contract (new wallet) creations from the Bittrex exchange, however, I'm more
       specifically looking to log everything with a 'create_0' Type Trace
       Address as shown in the below Etherscan link:

   https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1164ea62dc6ac087d9d4802a1a0fae6b366b292cd896ed69ec42f290418a7d2d#internal
3. Lastly, how do I record ETH transfers sent as Internal Transactions?
   Two examples below: a DEX ETH transfer & a smart contract ETH
   transfer, both have different 'Event Logs' according to Etherscan
   yet have a similar 'call_0' format under the 'Internal Transactions'
   tab.

   DEX ETH transfer:
   https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7ea52aad9bd16dd39353be31ffb532d7311c474d682ea2a7f378aa8afef5ad8c

   Smart Contract ETH transfer:
   https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf24b9c6de3f184bc729cf68193122b5d23f4517023824c049439d5e25d69fea6

Thanks

---

```
web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(i,j).then(function(v){
   web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(v.hash).then(function(r){

      tokenTransferHash = '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'
      contractInternalHash = '0xef4c8685c12779a52dae7549eb7defa8523f67a054ad425b877a6b2da469a331'

         for (var k = 0; k < r.logs.length; k++) {
            if((r.logs[k].topics[0] == tokenTransferHash) && (r.logs[k].topics.length == 3)) {

               //Code to Process ERC-20 Token Transfer Data
            }

            if(r.logs[k].topics[0] == contractInternalHash) {

               //Code to Process Internal Contract Creations
            }
         }
   }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
   });
}).catch(function(e) {
     console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**To answer the first part of your first question:**

> Are all ERC-20 token transfers are listed with the "0xddf252..." sha3 hash, and would the below code suffice for accurately capturing those transfers?

As far as I know, the ERC20 standard dictates the prototype of the `transfer` function, but it doesn't dictate the prototype of the `Transfer` event (or even the fact that this function should emit an event to begin with).

I might be wrong here, as evidently, OpenZeppelin have declared this event in their [IERC20 interface](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol#L69):

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

In either case, even if this event is not part of the ERC20 standard, it is widely acceptable to rely on it being emitted as a result of ERC20-token transfer operations.

A technical suggestion:

If you're using web3.js v1.x, then I recommend that you use this instead of that hard-coded value:

```
const tokenTransferHash = Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
```

Of course, you can initialize it once (i.e., in global scope, outside of any function).

---

**To answer the second part of your first question:**

> Is there a separate function for new tokens minted, or is it safe to assume all newly minted tokens come from the '0x000000...' address?

The ERC20 standard does not state that a `mint` function should be implemented to begin with.

So any ERC20-token contract which implements this function, is in fact extending the standard.

That said, it is widely acceptable that `mint` functions emit a `Transfer` event with the source address being zero, and that `burn` functions (also not part of the standard) emit a `Transfer` event with the target address being zero.

Of course, you should not rely on this fact without verifying it in the implementation of the contract that you're targeting.

Comment: The `Transfer` event is included in ERC20 - https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

Comment: @iamdefinitelyahuman: OK, thank you for the additional info. I'll leave the answer as is, because I kinda mentioned that anyway, and also in order to keep your comment above valid.